# How to make function to get page ancestors in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How I can get child pages for each page, if a page dont have any child then there must be shown right menu.

For Example:

- Parent Page

  - child page 1
  - child page 2

if parent don't have any child then display any menu

Right now I am using following code in:

**FUNCTION.PHP**

```
function get_top_ancestor_id() {
global $post;
if ($post->post_parent) {
    $ancestors = array_reverse(get_post_ancestors($post->ID));
    return $ancestors[0];
}
return $post-> ID;
```

}

**HEADER.PHP**

```
<?php
$args = array(
        'child_of' => get_top_ancestor_id(),
        'title_li' => ''
    );

?>
<?php wp_list_pages($args); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the default menu calling in wordpress

```
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly use this function

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahmad, if you just want to list the children of the page that you're currently on, you can use the function wp_get_post_parent_id (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_parent_id)

So, your code might be simplified to

```
<?php
global $post;
//If the page has children - print the list
if(wp_get_post_parent_id( $post->ID ))
{
    $args = array(
            'child_of' => wp_get_post_parent_id( $post->ID ),
            'title_li' => ''
    );
    wp_list_pages($args); 
}
else{
    $args = array(
            'child_of' => $post->ID,
            'title_li' => ''
    );
    wp_list_pages($args); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Actually i want to display children pages of each page.

For Example:

Parent Page is "Destinations"
Destinations have 7 Child Pages
i want to display that 7 child pages only on Destinations Page.

& 

Parent Parent Page is Tools
This page doesn't have any Child
so i want to display a menu on location of Childs

for Exact example you can Check on my Website             
[link](http://thetraveling.net)

Comment: I've made an update to the code for you that will display the menu on each parent page as well. If you are on the Destinations page, only the children of destinations will be listed. Also, if you are the destination page, all the children for that page will be listed too. I hope this is what you are looking for